# Missing disk drive in Eclipse Galileo

Tags: eclipse, startup, galileo

After extracting the Eclipse Galileo, it worked fine for a couple of days. But lately when ever I run it. It throws an exception/error :

Eclipse Galileo Error: there is no disk in the drive. please insert a disk into drive device harddisk2 dr2

Though I tried to remove it, and extract it again, however it still give me the same error!

Comment: Windows and i have already removed the workspace

Answer (score 1):

Some plugin probably remembers a drive you once used it with. Try deleting `workspace/.metadata` !

Under windows, the directory name may be slightly different, and it may be hidden. Find it, kill it!

This is a brute-force solution. But since you were already willing to tear down and re-install Galileo, I see no further harm in it.

Answer (score 1):

Read the exception literally - you don't have enough space on the hard-drive. Clean up some files and try again.

(by "cleanup some files" I mean - anywhere on the hard drive, not only in the workspace itself)